# How can I use reflection to help me load in an older version of .NET that an external SDK I am using requires?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, sdk

The company I work for wants to integrate our system with another company's .NET SDK, however I have run into an issue where our system is .NET 7.0 and their SDK requires .NET Framework 4.8. This company will not share details about what parts of their SDK require .NET 4.8, so I can't just use reflection for those specific libraries/assemblies.

I've been trying to find a way to integrate with them and I learned about reflection. How exactly can I use reflection to load in an older version of .NET Framework and also have that SDK use it? I've seen a number of posts about using reflection to load in older versions of other libraries/assemblies, however I haven't seen any for .NET and the most similar ones to my case are very dated and for WPF. None of the questions involved having some external SDK use that specific assembly version either, so I'm not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. You can try to use that sdk directly on .NET 7 and there is a chance this might work, but it's not reliable, you never know when it can fail (because uses api not available in .net 7). Alternative - write separate application working with sdk, and then run it in separate process. Use inter process communication to work with SDK. Best option - find another provider which can afford providing version for modern . NET.

Comment: I had a feeling that the lack of information online might mean it wasn't possible. I had tried to use the SDK regardless of the .NET requirement, and it threw some exceptions complaining about missing methods that no longer exist in the current version of .NET. I'll have to see how to set that up. Unfortunately I can't switch since this isn't a provider but a company that we are trying to partner with. Thanks for the help and advice!

Comment: Well in this case, IF your communication with SDK is not performance critical - just create separate .NET 4.8 console application and use SDK there, then let your main application communicate with SDK via this separate console application.

Comment: *"a company that we are trying to partner with"* - It sounds like they're not very interested in *partnering* with you. Given that they haven't bothered to update their SDK for an eventuality that has been coming -- and heavily publicized -- for a relatively long time now, they're just riding out old successes and they won't be a strong partner for very long, if ever. It will become increasingly more difficult to work with them as time goes on; this is the baseline for that difficulty.

Comment: @madreflection that's an incredibly shallow stance to take. There are many legacy applications around that are so incredibly hard to move to a newer .NET version, that a lot of companies are opting to release a new product rather than port their old one. This can take years to do and .NET isn't that old.

Comment: @Evk CthenB also suggested that so I think that will be the way I will have to implement it. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Usually a .NET version is equal accross all libraries, so it makes sense there is no additional information.

There's 3 solutions to incompatible versions:

1. Create an 'adapter' built in .NET 3.5 that fetches the required data and then outputs it in a format that your .NET 7.0 application can use.
2. Downgrade your own application to the supplier's version. This is actually preferred if you're just developing an extension or other limited-in-scope functionality.
3. Get the supplier to commit to a .NET upgrade, and close your ticket as 'won't fix'

Comment: 2 and 3 are unfortunately not possible for my situation, but 1 is an interesting idea. I will need to see if it is possible or not considering I don't know whether or not the external SDK I am using will place well with the adapter.

Comment: @ChristopherFernandez if you can access the external SDK with a .NET7 application, there's no reason you can't create a separate project in your solution with .NET 3.5 that you move your connection logic to (since that logic will need to work with the target SDK in the first place).